# Why is SynchronizationContext checked for null?

Tags: c#, multithreading

[InstallIfNeeded method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,7f026222b09e6594) of WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext class, in the try block:

```
SynchronizationContext currentContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
//Make sure we either have no [....] context
//or that we have one of type SynchronizationContext

if (currentContext == null || currentContext.GetType() == typeof(SynchronizationContext))
{
...
```

So first, `AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext` getter is called, and its return value is checked for null. Is checking for null necessary here?

Code of `AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext` below. It first checks if Current sync context is null, if it is, then a new one is created. So probably this getter never returns a null.

```
public static SynchronizationContext SynchronizationContext 
{
get 
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null) 
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
    }
    return SynchronizationContext.Current;
}
```

Comment: That comment there is a perfect example of a useless comment. It echoes what the code clearly specifies already.

Comment: @usr it checks `AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext` (which is the second code snippet). Its return value is checked for null, and if it returns `SynchronizationContext.Current`, so it **does** check `SynchronizationContext.Current` for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is checking for null necessary here?

My previous answer neglected the fact that `SynchronizationContext.Current` will in fact be created on a thread basis, and not across multiple threads (thanks to @PerSerAl for pointing that out). You can obviously see it in the code:

```
// Get the current SynchronizationContext on the current thread
public static SynchronizationContext Current 
{
    get      
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextReader().SynchronizationContext ??
               GetThreadLocalContext();
    }
}
```

Effectively, this does in-fact make the `null` check redundant, but does immune itself from any future changes that may happen in the future to code around `SynchronizationContext` implementation.

Comment: AFAIK, `SynchronizationContext.Current` is per thread property, so no synchronization necessary, as other threads can only set their own `SynchronizationContext`.

Answer (score 1):

With the exact code as it is right now, you are right.

However, look at the *intent* of the code instead. The point is that the only point where installing the winforms context is safe is when there is no other synchronization context. This corresponds to either having a `null` synchronization context, or the default `SynchronizationContext`.

The fact that the synchronization context can *never* be `null` *in current exact version of the code* is largely irrelevant. True, this will *probably* not change, since it's a public static interface, but depending on that is a completely unnecessary dependency. You want your code to signal it's intent as clearly as possible, and this check does exactly that - while also avoiding a direct dependency on the internal behaviour of a public interface.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I'm seeing (the first two bits are the same as your question):

```
SynchronizationContext currentContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
            //Make sure we either have no [....] context or that we have one of type SynchronizationContext
            if (currentContext == null || currentContext.GetType() == typeof(SynchronizationContext)) {
```

Which then goes to:

```
public static SynchronizationContext SynchronizationContext {
        get {
            if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null) {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
            }

            return SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }
```

Which then leads to: `in the line (SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());`

```
public static void SetSynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext syncContext)
    {
        ExecutionContext ec = Thread.CurrentThread.GetMutableExecutionContext();
        ec.SynchronizationContext = syncContext;
        ec.SynchronizationContextNoFlow = syncContext;
    }
```

But then it's returning the `SynchronizationContext.Current`

```
public static SynchronizationContext Current 
    {
        get      
        {
            return Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextReader().SynchronizationContext ?? GetThreadLocalContext();
        }
    }
```

Which **can potentially** end up here.

```
private static SynchronizationContext GetThreadLocalContext()
    {
        SynchronizationContext context = null;

#if FEATURE_APPX
        if (context == null && Environment.IsWinRTSupported)
            context = GetWinRTContext();
#endif

        return context;
    }
```

As you can see, `context` can be null if `IsWinRTSupported` returns false.

Based on what I'm seeing, the null check is probably a good idea. I don't know if the first condition `Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextReader().SynchronizationContext` can return null but given the `??` operator, that's a possibility.

Comment: if `SynchronizationContext.Current == null` is true, then `SetSynchronizationContext` will allocate a new synchronization context. It won't be `null` when returning.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov definitely a possibility. I didn't go in to whether `GetMutableExecutionContext()` is the same as `GetExecutionContextReader()` or not but based on what i saw with the `??`, I imagined it was a possibility that after `SetSynchronizationContext`, it was still null. I've personally never seen `SynchronizationContext` being null in a winforms application (but always null unless manually set in a console app) but I thought it might've been a possibility.

Comment: Seeing there's no `null` check around `ec`, I'd assume it can't, else you'd see a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: `ec` is this though:  `Thread.CurrentThread.GetMutableExecutionContext()` whereas the `Current` is trying to get the `Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextReader()`. These are two different method calls and I didn't check to see if the two are operating on the same thing. I suspect you're right and they're the same thing though (making the null check unnecessary) but I didn't dig deeper.